# JSF Page does not submit when onclick javascript is added to menu item?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, trinidad

I show some detail using popup windows. I want to close those when the user clicks on sign-out link. I have a JavaScript function that'll close the windows.
The sign-out link is rendered using Navigation MenuModel. The definition in faces-config is as below -

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>signoutNavigation</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.xxx.xxx.framework.NavigationItem</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>none</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>label</property-name>
        <value>Sign Out</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>viewId</property-name>
        <value>/signout.jsp</value>
    </managed-property> 
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>outcome</property-name>
        <value>signout</value>
    </managed-property> 
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>onclick</property-name>
        <value>closeOrderWindows()</value>
    </managed-property>     
</managed-bean>
```

The problem is when I use the "onclick" property on managed-bean, the page doesn't submit to "signout.jsp" and remains on same page.
When I remove/comment the "onclick" part, the page gets submitted properly.

I use MyFaces Trinidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to custom code in our NavigationItem.java class, which returned `null` when onclick property was provided.